# type conversion when pandas read csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to reduce the memory usage, then I used the code from:

```
https://www.kaggle.com/arjanso/reducing-dataframe-memory-size-by-65/notebook
```

and also save the column names and column types into pickle files, so that when read it from csv, I can auto converting the types as follow:

```
pkl_in = open('explore/col_types.pkl', "rb")
col_types = pickle.load(pkl_in)
pkl_in = open('explore/col_names.pkl', "rb")
mcol_names = pickle.load(pkl_in)
test_data=pd.read_csv('bb.csv',usecols=col_names,dtype=col_types,nrows=100)
```

But it shows the error:

```
ValueError: cannot safely convert passed user dtype of uint32 for float64 dtyped data in column 16
```

May I know how to force to convert to the types when reading csv?

Comment: HOw do you want to convert `5.6`. Should it be `5` or rounded to `6`?

Comment: if it is 5.6, will covert to float 32, still 5.6

Comment: But you are trying to convert it to `uint32`, that's what your error message says, isn't it?

Comment: @FlyingTeller yes, but I wish to force it to convert

Comment: @sweetyBaby If you have floats, you can use `float32` instead of `uint32` as they both take 32 bits per object. Just for information, this site also gives a few good tips: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/pandas-big-data/

Comment: @ysearka but the range is different, to use uint32, can minimize the bits but also have the larger range comparing with float 32

Comment: My question still stands. As you are apparently trying to convert `float64` to `uint32`, then how do you want to handle the conversion? If your `float64` is `5.6`, then what should the resulting `uint32` look like?

Comment: @FlyingTeller you can check the website I provided, it will check the min, max number, then decide to convert to uint32 or float32

Comment: Looking at your website, your statement is not completely true. There are two checks. One is if the column can be "safely" converted to an integer, by converting the column to int, subtracting the result from the original column and then adding that up to check if it results in 0. The idea is probably to check if the float typed column only consists of `5.0` or `2.0` that can be safely coverted to integer without losses. You should be careful there though since that code would tell you that a column with `-0.4` and `0.4` could be safely converted to int, but that is for you to decide.

Comment: You probably need the `converters` argument of the `read_csv` function